# Converting VB code set2.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(0).Item("Example") to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, dataset, rows

I know that the VB code `set2.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("EXAMPLE")` translates to `set2.Tables(0).Rows(0)["EXAMPLE"]` in C#. However, there is a similar piece of code in the same program in VB written as `set2.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(0).Item("Example").` Is `Tables.Item(0)` just another way of writing `Tables(0)` in VB? And if this is the case, would the translation in C# be `set2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EXAMPLE"]`?

Comment: In C#, your code should be: `set2.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item["EXAMPLE"]`. To index arrays or lists in C#, you use square brackets instead of parenthesis.

Comment: In C# it says Item is not an extension of the method. I know about the brackets. I read somewhere that Item is already implied in C#, so there is no use in using them.

Comment: In addition to what @icemanind says above, you are also getting confused by the fact that a `DataTableCollection` has an `Item` property so `Tables[0]` is the same as `Tables.Item[0]`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfsd7dz4(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1